# lxml, <br/> и пропадающий tail

Tags: python, lxml

Пытаюсь тут сайт парсить, и обнаружил, что между тегами <br/> пропадает перенос строки:

```
>>> e = lxml.html.fromstring('<div>a<br/>\n<br/>\nb</div>')
>>> lxml.html.tostring(e, method='xml', encoding='utf-8')
'<div>a<br/><br/>\nb</div>'
>>> e.findall('br')[0].tail
None
>>> e.findall('br')[1].tail
'\nb'
```

Не то чтобы критично, но немного неприятно. Отчего он пропадает и возможно ли его как-то вернуть не вручную?

Что-то похожее было на [соседнем stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469361/lxml-removes-spaces-and-line-breaks-in-head), но там проблема с head и решилась обновлением, а у меня вот не решилась.

При парсинге через `html5lib` перенос строки на месте, но для моих целей он слишком медленный.

**UPD**: Описанная выше ситуация — на 32-битном Debian 7, Python 2.7.3 и на lxml 3.4.4. На домашнем ноутбуке на 64-битном Arch на Python 2.7.9 и таком же lxml 3.4.4 всё внезапно работает нормально. o_O

Comment: касательно примера: в пайтоне одинарные/двойные кавычки влияют на интерпретацию \n?

Comment: @norbornen Не влияют. Но есть, например, «сырые» строки r'\n' и r"\n", чтобы \n воспринимался питоном именно как \n, а не как перенос строки

Comment: У меня выражение `lxml.html.tostring(e, method='xml', encoding='utf-8')` возвращает ожидаемую строку  `b'<div>a<br/>\n<br/>\nb</div>'`. Какую версию python и библиотеки вы используете? Я проверял под python 3.4 и lxml 3.4.3.0

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev 2.7, 3.4.4, но, как оказалось, на домашнем ноуте поведение отчего-то правильное, обновил вопрос (подозреваю, тут уже, возможно, придётся на чей-то баг-трекер отправиться)

Comment: В чё причина, так и не разобрался, просто обновил Debian с 7 на 8 — проблема пропала. :) (может, удалить вопрос?)