# Загадка с символами в XML тегах при его парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Привет всем!

Столкнулся с какой-то неопределенной проблемой. Не понимаю в чем суть и как её разрешить.

Дан некоторый XML файл и его содержимое:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация>
<ИдКлассификатора>555</ИдКлассификатора>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Следующий код на Python 3.6.3 выдаст ошибку:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('321-555.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print('root = {} tag = {}, attrib = {}'.format(root, root.tag, root.attrib))
print('Количество элементов в root = ', len(root))

for child in root:
    print('child.tag={} child.attrib={}'.format(child.tag, child.attrib))
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readxml.py", line 4, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse('321-555.xml')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 30: 
unexpected end of data
```

Что удалось мне понять? Практически ничего, но если поиграться с тегом `<ИдКлассификатора>` то ошибка исчезнет. Например, можно удалить последний символ `а` или заменить его на символ `o`, то ошибка уйдет.

Казалось бы, проблема в символе `а`, но это не так!!! Может проблема с этим символом в конце имени тега? Попробуем заменить элемент на этот добавив в конец символ `м`:

```
<ИдКлассификаторам>555</ИдКлассификаторам>
```

Ошибки нет! Можно сделать логическое заключение, что что-то с символом `а` в конце имени тега. Но расслабляться еще рано )) Добавим новый тег `<Свойства>` с символом `а` на конце, вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация>
<ИдКлассификаторам>555</ИдКлассификаторам>
<Свойства></Свойства>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Думаете будет ошибка? Неа! Не будет ))) O_o

Почему так? Что это за ошибка? Как исправить?

Comment: Файл xml сохранён **не** в utf-8.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov сохранен в UTF-8, по крайней мере это показывает Visual Studio Code, Notepad++, а также пробовал перекодировать с помощью python, ничего не вышло (( Также, этот тег набирал вручную посимвольно (не копируя) - тоже, положительного результата не дало.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Плюс ко всему, даже если бы файл был сохранен в другой кодировке или что-то еще, то почему тогда с тегом <Свойства> не происходит ошибки где также есть этот символ?

Comment: У меня на Python 3.4 все нормально работает, все коды скопировал прямо из вопроса.

Comment: Увы, у меня тоже всё отлично работает

Comment: Впрочем, невоспроизводимые баги lxml [случались и у меня тоже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420027)

Comment: @andreymal - действительно, на другой версии python ошибка не воспроизводится. Попытался на debian stretch, python 3.5.3 - ошибки нет. Ошибка у меня воспроизводится на kUbuntu 17.10, python 3.6.3 с самыми последними обновлениями.

Answer (score 1):

Опытным путем было установлено, что ошибка возникает на версии python 3.6.3. Было проверено на версиях python 3.5.3, и следующей версии python 3.6.**4** - ошибка не воспроизводится.

Решение: Обновить/изменить версию python